# Change Index in OrientDB

Tags: sql, indexing, orientdb, gremlin

I'm new on **OrientDB**. How can I change the searching index to **Hash Indexing** (Database:GratefulDeadConcerts) . I don't understand that what is written in Orient DB Dpcs. I use the Orient DB Studio.

Comment: Don't keep asking the same question.

Answer (score 3):

Provided the index was created as a `Hash` type index. You can look it up by using this command : `select from index:<index-name> where key = <key>` as explained and documented in [OrientDB Manual Indexes](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Indexes.html).